# Kill the previous command in a pipeline

Tags: linux, bash, awk, waf, ns-3

I am running a simulation like this

```
./waf --run scratch/myfile | awk -f filter.awk
```

How can I kill the `waf` command as soon as `filter.awk` detects that something happened (e.g. after a specific line is read)?

I cannot change `waf` or `myfile`. I can only change `filter.awk`, and the above command (obviously).

***Update after comments:***

- `waf` does not terminated after receiving `SIGPIPE` (as it should?)
- It spawns child processes, that need cleaning up.

This is [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14911916/828193) *(and challenge)*.

---

After working on @thatotherguy's ans @Chris's answers, I simplified a bit and got this:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
{ ./waf --run scratch/myfile & echo $! > "$tmp"; } | { awk -f filter.awk; pkill -P $(<$tmp); kill $(<$tmp); }
```

Unfortunately I could not get rid of the `tmp` file, every attempt to pass the `PID` as a variable failed.

I won't change the accepted answer (since it was the one that worked when it was *really* needed), but +1 for anyone that can simplify more.

Comment: You can use `pkill -P $(<$tmp); kill $(<$tmp)` to kill all processes whose PPID is your waf instance, and finally the waf instance itself.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes with that change a get no processes left running. Would you like to convert the comment to an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you very much for your help! I would never solve it by my self...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes this tricky is that `waf` misbehaves by not exiting when the pipe breaks, and it spawns off a second process that we also have to get rid off:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
cat <(./waf --run scratch/myfile & echo $! > "$tmp"; wait) | awk -f filter.awk; 
pkill -P $(<$tmp)
kill $(<$tmp)
```

- We use `<(process substitution)` to run `waf` in the background and write its pid to a temp file.
- We use `cat` as an intermediary to relay data from this process to awk, since `cat` will exit properly when the pipe is broken, allowing the pipeline to finish.
- When the pipeline's done, we kill all processes that `waf` has spawned (by Parent PID)
- Finally we kill `waf` itself.

Answer (score 4):

Use `awk`'s `exit` statement. `waf` should exit as soon as the pipe connecting it to `awk` closes.

Comment: Tried with `exit -1` and `exit 0`. `awk` terminates, but `waf` keeps running.

Comment: Does `waf` output more lines shortly after awk exits? Otherwise it won't notice awk's not there anymore.

Comment: @thatotherguy  I filtered lines starting with `TraceDelay` for testing. Without exit, it prints continuously. With exit, printing stops, but prompt does not return (pressing enter does not help). I will update question to clarify

Comment: See if `waf --run scratch/myfile | false` also hangs. If it does, you can use `cat <(waf --run scratch/myfile) | awk -f filter.awk`. The pipeline should then end, and you can `killall waf` or similar afterwards

Comment: @thatotherguy: feel free to edit my answer (or add your own), as I don't fully understand how using `cat` as an intermediary fixes the problem. Is it an issue of `waf` not trying to write to the closed pipeline?

Comment: Unaccepting because I am left with the `myfile` proccess running afterwords. Sorry :)

Comment: That was what the `killall waf` part was for. If `myfile` becomes a separate process, you'd have to kill that manually too.

Comment: @chepner Apparently `waf` just ignores the write error and SIGPIPE, and keeps on processing. `cat` does not misbehave in this way, so when the pipe is broken, it exits, allowing the pipeline to end.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you for your help. With `kill XXXX`, where `XXXX` is the PID of myfile i can kill it manually. But I want to do it automatically so that it can be integrated in a script

Comment: @user000001 kill works in scripts as well. To get the specific pid, you can use: `tmp=$(mktemp); cat <(waf .. & echo $! > "$tmp"; wait) | awk ..; kill -9 $(<$tmp)`

Comment: @thatotherguy I updated my answer with the result of your last comment. I think you are close to finding a solution. The only problem is that the parent process terminated, but not the child process. `kill -SIGINT` did not help within the script.

Answer (score 1):

When `awk` exits, `waf` gets a `SIGPIPE` the next time it tries to write output, which should cause it to exit unless whoever wrote `waf` deliberately set it up to ignore `SIGPIPE`s telling it to exit, in which case you'll have to kill it manually with `kill` or some such.  Something like:

```
./waf --run scratch/myfile | ( awk -f filter.awk; killall waf )
```

You might need a `-KILL` option to `killall` if `waf` is ignoring all exit signals.

Comment: With this I got `waf: no process found`, but no prompt.

Comment: Also would `killall` affect other `waf` instances running from the same script?